# Cannot activate my virtualenv in project folder, I get the error arguments required dest. (windows 10, Powershell)

Tags: python, django, windows, powershell, virtualenv

Going through FreeCodeCamp Django: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t

I have installed my virtual Environment on Windows 10 using Powershell, but when trying to activate my virtualenv I get the error arguments required dest.

Interestingly when I type virtualenv --version, in my project folder it will return the version. However when I type just virtualenv, I receive the error in the title. I am using powershell.

Having trouble activating / deactivating..

Answer (score 0):

[from_the_docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments): virtualenv is just a module. You need to create an environment after installing this module. You can do this by running:

```
python3 -m venv env1
```

and then activate this **envi** environment by running command

```
env1\Scripts\activate
```